# How to translate a query executed by a cursor in a pandas data frame? (Databricks)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, databricks

I've got a script that executes a query by a cursor in SQL (this is the only way to make a query in that Data base). I've to analyse its data, unfortunately it's so hard to make it with a cursor, I've tried to translate it into a pandas data frame but I've couldn't. The script is as follow:

```
from databricks import sql
import os

connection = sql.connect(
                        server_hostname = "hostname",
                        http_path = "http_path",
                        access_token = "token")
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * from schema.table limit 10")
print(cursor.fetchall())

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Could you help me or guide me on how to translate this cursor into a Pandas Dataframe?

Answer (score 4):

First get pandas `pip install pandas`. then for your question you could use it like that.

```
from databricks import sql
import os
import pandas as pd

connection = sql.connect(
    server_hostname="hostname",
    http_path="http_path",
    access_token="token")
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * from schema.table limit 10")

column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
data = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)

print(df)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```